# Scale height and width of all control inside viewbox

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF. In my code i have a simple WPF window with a few controls. All the controls are contained in the View Box. My problem is that when i resize the the window, the control size text is not resizing proportionately. Here is my code:

```
<Window x:Class="DesktopGoogleReader.UIelements.About"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="About" Height="346" Width="435"
    >
    <Window.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,0.5">
            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#eee" />
                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#ccc" />
            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Window.Background>
    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
        <Grid>        
            <Label Height="41" Margin="83,12,12,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold">Desktop Google Reader</Label>
            <Image Margin="348,0,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" Height="65" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65" Source="C:\Users\TRIDIP\Desktop\tmp\Desktop Google Reader WPF good UI\trunk\DesktopGoogleReader\DesktopGoogleReader.ico" />
            <Label Height="28" Margin="92,49,12,0" Name="label_versionName" VerticalAlignment="Top">Version: Versionnumber</Label>
            <TextBlock Margin="12,83,12,0" Name="textBlock1" Height="54" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="Desktop Google Reader is Windows / .NET based client to the RSS aggregation service Google Reader. It is licensed under the New BSD License (BSD). It is developed by Konstantins Onufrijevs and Sven Walther" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            <Label Margin="12,134,12,0" Name="label2" Height="29" VerticalAlignment="Top">Credits: Desktop Google Reader uses the following external resources:</Label>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,161,0,0" Name="button_snarlChsarp" Width="173" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top" >Snarl Connector</Button>
            <Button Margin="191,161,0,0" Name="button_TweetSharp" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="173" >TweetSharp</Button>
            <Button Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,190,0,0" Name="button_iconSet" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="173" >Function Icon Set</Button>
            <Button Height="23" Margin="191,190,0,0" Name="button_facebook" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="173" >Facebook Developer Toolkit</Button>
            <Button Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,219,0,0" Name="button_awesomium" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="173" >Web Kit .NET</Button>
            <Button Height="23" Margin="191,219,0,0" Name="button_winkle" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="173" >Winkle Update System</Button>
            <TextBlock Height="59" Margin="12,248,12,0" Name="textBlock_contributors" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="Contributors: We want to thank all the people using Desktop Google Reader. A special thanks goes to Henry C. for his continues help in improving and supporting our project." TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 3):

Need to modify the Stretch.

Uniform will keep the text proportional.
You are probably looking for Fill.

[Stretch Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch)

Don't set the height and widths of a control it is not going to resize.
And put the Viewbox in the Grid (not Grid in the Viewbox).

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Viewbox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Stretch="Fill">
        <TextBox Text="size me" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" />
    </Viewbox>
    <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Stretch="Fill">
        <TextBox Text="size me to0 " TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" />
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: i am not talking about text. i want all the controls like textblock button etc inside viewbox should increase & decrease proportionately when window will be resize. so guide me how to do it. thanks

Comment: Then work on the wording to you question "control size text is not resizing proportionately".  Since you have fixed size (height and width they are not going to size.